# Integration of circleci in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, circleci

Got struck on creating config file for circleci. This is my config file created under circleci folder(.circleci -> config.yml).

```
  version: 2.0
    jobs:
      build:
        working_directory: ~/electrik_backend
        docker:
          - image: circleci/ruby:2.4.1-node-browsers
          - image: postgres:9.6.2-alpine
            environment:
              POSTGRES_USER: postgres 
              POSTGRES_DB: postgres_test
        steps:
          - checkout

          # Bundle install dependencies
          - run:
              name: Install dependencies
              command: bundle check --path=vendor/bundle || bundle install --path=vendor/bundle --jobs 4 --retry 3

          # Restore bundle cache
          - restore_cache:
              keys:
                - rails-demo-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
                - rails-demo-

          # Store bundle cache
          - save_cache:
              key: rails-demo-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
              paths:
                - vendor/bundle

          - run:
              name: install dockerize
              command: wget https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize/releases/download/$DOCKERIZE_VERSION/dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz && sudo tar -C /usr/local/bin -xzvf dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz && rm dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz
              environment:
                DOCKERIZE_VERSION: v0.3.0
          - run:
              name: Wait for db
              command: dockerize -wait tcp://localhost:5432 -timeout 1m 

          # Setup the database
          - run: bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate
          - run: rails db:test:prepare
          - run: rspec
```

Untill database everything is working, but at setup of database getting error as `rake aborted!
Cannot load`Rails.application.database_configuration`:
Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"]`. my config.yml file is

```
    development:
      adapter: postgresql
      encoding: unicode
      database: electrik_development
      host: localhost
      pool: 5
      username: postgres
      password: test123

    test:
      adapter: postgresql
      encoding: unicode
      database: electrik_test
      host: localhost
      pool: 5
      username: postgres
      password: test123
```

Comment: Try running an `ls` in the directory to make sure your file is in fact checked out and matching the location rake expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the database setup and run tests.

```
  # Setup the database
  - run: mv config/database.yml.sample config/database.yml
  - run: RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:create
  - run: bundle exec rake db:setup

  # Run the tests
  - type: shell
    command: |
      bundle exec rspec --profile 10 \
                        --out test_results/rspec.xml \
                        --format progress \
                        $(circleci tests glob "spec/**/*_spec.rb" | circleci tests split --split-by=timings)
```

I prefer to set host **127.0.0.1** for CircleCI